# Webflux - Read mono (request) multiple times

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

Firstly, I am confused if there is any benefit using reactive handler method parameters.
Secondly, I am experiencing some issue using this technique when I need to read these parameters multiple times.

```
public Mono<TokenDto> generateToken(Mono<UserDto> user) {
        var userDto = user.block();
        return userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail())
                .filter(foundUser -> bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(userDto.getPassword(), foundUser.getPassword()))
                .map(foundUser -> JWT.create()
                        .withSubject(foundUser.getEmail())
                        .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + jwtTtl.toMillis()))
                        .withClaim(USER_ROLES_CLAIM, foundUser.getRoles().stream().map(RoleEnum::name).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                        .sign(Algorithm.HMAC512(jwtSecret))
                )
                .map(TokenDto::new);
    }
```

As you can see, I need to block to actually read parameter twice. I tried to zipWith the userRepository result but then I end up with Mono in the Tuple2 structure.

Does Reactor have any solution to this? Maybe there is a function publish/repeat which might by promissing. I have managed to build a pipe but there has been always error in reading request body multiple times.

Thank you.

Error:

```
"timestamp": "2020-07-03T06:24:23.592+00:00",
    "path": "/login",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Request body is missing: public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.ostrozlik.taskagent.web.dto.TokenDto>> com.ostrozlik.taskagent.web.controller.UserController.login(reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.ostrozlik.taskagent.web.dto.UserDto>)",
    "requestId": "defc8953-1",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebInputException: 400 BAD_REQUEST \"Request body is missing: public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.ostrozlik.taskagent.web.dto.TokenDto>> com.ostrozlik.taskagent.web.controller.UserController.login(reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.ostrozlik.taskagent.web.dto.UserDto>)\"\n\tat org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.handleMissingBody(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:230)\n\tSuppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: \nError has been observed at the following site(s):\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.ostrozlik.taskagent.web.controller.UserController#login(Mono) [DispatcherHandler]\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST \"/login\" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]\nStack trace:\n\t\tat org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.handleMissingBody(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:230)\n\t\tat org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.lambda$readBody$5(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:194)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:70)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4219)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2016)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:174)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextStart.java:115)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:336)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:384)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1783)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:152)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:135)\n\t\tat reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:294)\n\t\tat reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.lambda$subscribe$2(FluxReceive.java:138)\n\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)\n\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)\n\t\tat io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384)\n\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)\n\t\tat io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\n\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)\n\t\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)\n"
}
```

Comment: Notice about your example. `bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches` could be cpu-intensive (depends on cost parameter). So maybe you should move its calculation to parrallel scheduler. There is a risk to hang your application, if too many parallel requests will calculate bcrypt hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do it this way, which won't subscribe to user twice.

```java
public Mono<TokenDto> generateToken(Mono<UserDto> user) {
    return user
        .flatMap(userDto ->
            userRepository
                .findByEmail(userDto.getEmail())
                //filter is inside flatmap
                .filter(foundUser -> bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(userDto.getPassword(), foundUser.getPassword()))
        )
        .map(foundUser -> JWT.create()
            .withSubject(foundUser.getEmail())
            .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + jwtTtl.toMillis()))
            .withClaim(USER_ROLES_CLAIM, foundUser.getRoles().stream().map(RoleEnum::name).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .sign(Algorithm.HMAC512(jwtSecret))
        )
        .map(TokenDto::new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could come up with using `zip`. Why do you think it's not right to have a `Mono` in the `tuple2` structure?

```
public Mono<TokenDto> generateToken(Mono<UserDto> user) {

        return Mono.zip(user,user.flatMap(a -> userRepository.findByEmail(a.getEmail())))
                   .filter(tuple2 -> bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(tuple2.getT1().getPassword(), tuple2.getT2().getPassword()))
                   .map(tuple2 -> tuple2.getT2())
                   .map(foundUser -> {//your mapping logic})
                   .map(TokenDto::new);

    }
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it works for you and if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: This is not working sadly. But the other answer does. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: What's not working in this, if I may ask? What the error?

Comment: I got an error described in my question and as I see it now, it really happens. You version of zip actually reads the same publisher twice.

Answer (score 0):

while [@123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123)'s answer is perfect
there is another "pattern" we can try to avoid nesting
we create a "context object", that "holds a reference to all interactions", so it can be easily used to retrieve them at any point

*it might not be beneficial in this simple example, but probably it would be when trying more number of operations*

```java
public Mono<TokenDto> generateToken(Mono<UserDto> user) {

  Context ctx = new Context();

  return user
    .doOnNext(ctx::setUserDto) // set ctx
    .flatMap((_v) -> userRepository.findByEmail(ctx.getUserDto().getEmail())) // use ctx
    .doOnNext(ctx::setUserEntity) // set ctx
    .filter((_v) -> bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(
      ctx.getUserDto().getPassword(),
      ctx.getUserEntity().getPassword())
    ) // use ctx
    .map((_v) -> JWT.create()
      .withSubject(ctx.getUserEntity().getEmail())
      .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + jwtTtl.toMillis()))
      .withClaim(USER_ROLES_CLAIM, ctx.getUserEntity().getRoles()...)
      .sign(Algorithm.HMAC512(jwtSecret))
    )
    .map(TokenDto::new);
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Context {

  private UserEntity userEntity;

  private UserDto userDto;
}
```